# Manually Deploy Code in GIT from Bitbucket to a Production Server

Tags: git, deployment, bitbucket

I read a number of articles on the web and on StackOverflow on deploying GIT from central private Bitbucket repo to a live server. However, I could not find an article that satisfies the following requirements:

1. Deployment is manual (i.e, I can manually deploy changes, and not automatically push them immediately as they become ready)
2. Do not use any third party tool
3. Be able to do so without creating a special account on the live server if possible (this may be challenging, not sure)
4. Pushing code results in updated changes, without a copy of the repo files (no .git directory) - Again, not sure if this is possible

Is this even possible? If so, how can I do it? Can you post details?

Comment: Your question is very vague. You don't even mention the technology you're using. The closest response that seems applicable is to recommend you check out Heroku, a hosted service that allows you to do a "git push" of your code resulting in it being automatically built and deployed. Heroku has inspired a number of open source look-alikes which could be used internally

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I do not think the technology being used is important. What is important is I have GIT on Bitbucket, and I like to push it to be deployed. I was hoping I do not user a service like Heroku or any third party, just a way to push, like a script. Anyway, thanks, I will look into Heroku in more detail.

Comment: @Greeso Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: I did come up with a complex solution that works in AWS environment. If you like to know the details then let me know. I am asking if you need it, and didn't post the answer, because it is AWS and WordPress (which was outside the scope of my original question)